# How can i create a transition for my navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, transition

I created on my Website a JS, which toggles me a class, to push the whole website to te left side and hide the navigation.

How can i add a transition to let the website slide to the left side?

JS

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var body = $('body');
    $('.menu-toggle').bind('click', function() {
      body.toggleClass('menu-open');
      return false;
    });
  })();
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.divright{
    Background-color: #F76926;
    height: 500px;
    width: 76.5%;
    float: right;
    border-radius:20px;
    padding-left: 3%;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
}

.buttondiv {
    height: 2.5%;
    width: 3%;
    z-index:1;
    float:center;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 20%
}

.divleft{
    Background-color: #4B4B4B;
    height: 500px;
    width: 19.5%;
    float: left;
    border-radius:20px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}

.menu-open{
    left:-20%;
}
```

Comment: If you would set a fiddle or similar it would be easier to help you

Comment: In CSS you may add transition

    .menu-open{
    left:-20%;
    transition:1s;
    }

Comment: Thanks for your amswer, i tried it, but it doesn't work, do i need to change .divleft{position: relative;} maybe?